# Vuetify DataTable - align cell content vertically

Tags: html, css, vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

I've added a `v-select` to one of `v-data-table` cells. I'm having problems with alignment. I want the input to be centered. Right now it doesn't look good.

[image]

How to do that? I tried to add `align:'center'` to the table headers but it did not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space below `v-select` is reserved for input details (validation error messages). If you don't need it, add `hide-details` property to `v-select`.